# How to combine all code-splitted modules into a single file?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, commonschunkplugin

I've got an SPA for which I want to split the non-critical code and load it asynchronously right after the critical file is being loaded, but as a single file.

To this end, I'm utilizing `import('./module-name')` as code-splitting points.

Problem is, in the resulting output, I've got multiple files:

[image]

I tried utilizing `CommonsChunkPlugin` with this config:

```
  new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ['app'],
    children: true,
    async: true,
  })
```

And got this result:

[image]

While it's nice that `aws-sdk` is not being duplicated anymore, we're still seeing multiple files in the output.

Again, my goal is to have a single file with the critical code (app.js) and another file for all code that has been split out (0.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by using `LimitChunkCountPlugin` alongside:

```
  new LimitChunkCountPlugin({
    maxChunks: 3 //I'll be wondering about the 3 till the day I die
  }),
```

Described in [the docs](https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/bundle-splitting/). Who knew.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. When I put 2, for some weird reason it stop working. Do you manage to solve it in another way? Or just use it with 3?..

Comment: Yep, I still have 3 over there. Haven't thought about it since. It works. I'm happy.